# How to scale an image without occasionally inverting it (with the Python Imaging Library)

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

When resizing images along the lines shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400788/resize-image-in-python-without-losing-exif-data) occasionally the resulting image is inverted. About 1% of the images I resize are inverted, the rest is fine. So far I was unable to find out what is different about these images.

See [resized example](http://images.hudora.de/640x480/NIRV2MRR3XJGR52JATL6BOVMQMFSV54I01.jpeg) and [original image](http://images.hudora.de/o/NIRV2MRR3XJGR52JATL6BOVMQMFSV54I01.jpeg) for examples.

Any suggestions on how to track down that problem?

Comment: I can't see images from the links

Comment: Try http://images.hudora.de/640x480/NIRV2MRR3XJGR52JATL6BOVMQMFSV54I01.jpeg and http://images.hudora.de/o/NIRV2MRR3XJGR52JATL6BOVMQMFSV54I01.jpeg

Comment: The second image is broken (on Google Chrome).

Comment: Be aware that after patching PIL the images at the above URLS are *not* inverted anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to find someone experienced in JPEG and with some additional knowledge was able to find a solution.

1. JPEG is a very underspecified
   Format.
2. The second image is a valid JPEG but it is in CMYK color space, not in RGB color space.
3. Design minded tools (read: things from Apple) can process CMYK JPEGs, other stuff (Firefox, IE) can't.
4. CMYK JPEG is *very* under specified and the way Adobe Photoshop writes it to disk is borderline to buggy.

Best of it all [there is a patch](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2006-April/003871.html) to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your original image won't display for me; Firefox says

```
The image “http://images.hudora.de/o/NIRV2MRR3XJGR52JATL6BOVMQMFSV54I01.jpeg” 
cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.
```

This suggests that the problem arises when you attempt to resize a corrupted JPEG, and indeed your resized example shows what looks like JPEG corruption to my eye (Ever cracked open a JPEG image and twiddled a few bits to see what it does to the output? I have, and a few of my abominable creations looked like that). There are a few JPEG repair tools out there, but I've never seriously tried any of them and don't know if they might be able to help you out.

Comment: same in chrome, but IrfanView can open them, so it must be an error in the image

Comment: On MacOS I was open it "everywhere" (Safari, Preview) - so I never thought of the original image being corrupt. Thanks for the hint!