# python, copy exif data from one image to other

Tags: python, opencv, exif

I am reading image using OpenCV and python.

```
img=cv2.imread('orig.jpg')
```

and after modifying the image, I save it again.

```
cv2.imwrite('modi.jpg', img)
```

But now its EXIF data is lost.

How can I copy EXIF from orig.jpg to `'modi.jpg'`.

I tried [EXIF 1.3.5](https://pypi.org/project/exif/)

```
with open('orig.jpg', 'rb') as img_file:
     img1 = Image(img_file)

with open('modi.jpg', 'wb') as new_image_file:
       new_image_file.write(img1.get_file())
```

But it overwrites the image data of `modi.jpg` also.

Comment: This should help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770121/copying-and-writing-exif-information-from-one-image-to-another-using-pyexiv2

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you simply want to copy EXIF from one image to another, an easy was might be this.

```
from PIL import Image
# load old image and extract EXIF
image = Image.open('orig.jpg')
exif = image.info['exif']

# load new image
image_new = Image.open('modi.jpg')
image_new.save('modi_w_EXIF.jpg', 'JPEG', exif=exif)
```

I found this example amongst others [here](https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/resize-image-in-python-without-losing-exif-data/). I noticed this method copied the image thumbnail (not the image information!) to the new file. You might want to set the thumbnail anew.

Another example from the same page seems to be even simpler:

```
import jpeg
jpeg.setExif(jpeg.getExif('orig.jpg'), 'modi.jpg')
```

I couldn't install the required module and test it, though, but it might be worth a try.

**Concerning the `EXIF` module:**

You overwrite the image because `img1` is not just the EXIF data but the entire image. You would have to do the following steps:

1. load the image containing the EXIF info and get that information
2. load the new image which lacks that info
3. overwrite the new image's EXIF
4. save the new image with EXIF

Something in the likes of:

```
f_path_1 = "path/to/original/image/with/EXIF.jpg"
f_path_2 = "path/to/new/image/without/EXIF.jpg"
f_path_3 = "same/as/f_path_2/except/for/test/purposes.jpg"

from exif import Image as exIm # I imported it that way because PIL also uses "Image"
with open(f_path_1, "rb") as original_image:
     exif_template = exIm(original_image)
if not exif_template.has_exif:
    Warning("No EXIF data found for " + f_path_1)
tags = exif_template.list_all()

with open(f_path_2, "rb") as new_rgb_image:
     exif_new = exIm(new_rgb_image)

for tag in tags:
    try:
        exec("exif_new." + tag + "=exif_template." + tag)
    except:
        pass

with open(f_path_3, "wb") as new_rgb_image:
     new_rgb_image.write(exif_new.get_file())
```

Note: For some reason `EXIF` was only able to write some, but not all tags from the original image when I tried it.