# python PIL resize image maintaining EXIF metadata

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I'm using a combination of exiftool and PIL to geotag and resize imagery. I've geotagged the full resolution images and now want to create lower resolution images for web hosting. Using PIL I have resized them but it looses the Geotag data. does anyone know of a way to maintain the EXIF metadata on the img.save

many thanks

```
basewidth = 3680
img = Image.open(INPUTFILE)
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(INPUTFILE + "_LowRes.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import jpeg
jpeg.setExif(jpeg.getExif('foo.jpg'), 'foo-resized.jpg')
```

http://www.emilas.com/jpeg/

Answered here: 
[Resize image in Python without losing EXIF data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400788/resize-image-in-python-without-losing-exif-data)